# Get IP address of an interface on Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

How can I get the [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address of an interface on Linux from C code?

For example, I'd like to get the IP address (if any) assigned to eth0.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> /* for strncpy */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main()
{
 int fd;
 struct ifreq ifr;

 fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

 /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */
 ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

 /* I want IP address attached to "eth0" */
 strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

 ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);

 close(fd);

 /* display result */
 printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

 return 0;
}
```

The code sample is taken from [here](http://www.geekpage.jp/en/programming/linux-network/get-ipaddr.php).

Comment: why there is a segmentation fault?

Comment: If you change `SIOCGIFADDR` to `SIOCGIFNETMASK`, you can get the interface's netmask.

Comment: It's worth checking the return value of `ioctl()`, and if it's non-zero, check the value of `errno`.

Comment: No need for `IFNAMSIZ-1`, instead just `IFNAMSIZ` will suffice. strncpy will use the last byte to terminate the string incase of overflow.

Comment: @zapstar I don't think that's correct. From the `strncpy` manpage: _Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated._

Comment: @MarkSmith Yes you are correct, I was under the wrong impression that `strncpy` does terminate the string with NULL byte. Thanks for pointing this out for me.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, will it return all IP attached to the same nic?

Answer (score 49):

In addition to the ioctl() method Filip demonstrated you can use [getifaddrs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).  There is an example program at the bottom of the man page.

Comment: getifaddrs seems very comprehensive. Other methods will only give the primary or first address per interface.

Comment: I don't have any connection on eth0, if I use the other method it outputs 128.226.115.183 which is wrong. However, this method shows that there is no connection on eth0 which provides a reliable output

Answer (score 31):

If you're looking for an address (IPv4) of the specific interface say **wlan0** then
try this code which uses [getifaddrs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html):

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
    int family, s;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];

    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) 
    {
        perror("getifaddrs");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) 
    {
        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;  

        s=getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in),host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);

        if((strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,"wlan0")==0)&&(ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET))
        {
            if (s != 0)
            {
                printf("getnameinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("\tInterface : <%s>\n",ifa->ifa_name );
            printf("\t  Address : <%s>\n", host); 
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You can replace **wlan0** with **eth0** for ethernet and **lo** for local loopback.

The structure and detailed explanations of the data structures
used could be found [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/4/networking/).

To  know more about linked list in C this [page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html) will be a good starting point.

Comment: why we need `getnameinfo`?

Comment: @abhiarora   From the doc - it converts a socket address to a corresponding host and service, in a protocol-independent manner. Note that the value of the `host` parameter printed later is supplied inside the `getnameinfo` function.

Comment: Why `ifa->ifa_addr == NULL`  is not enough? I am not sure why we need `getnameinfo` as ifa_addr is internal address.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents: the same code works even if iOS:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>



#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    showIP();
}



void showIP()
{
    struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
    int family, s;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];

    if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1)
    {
        perror("getifaddrs");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
    {
        if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;

        s=getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in),host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);

        if( /*(strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,"wlan0")==0)&&( */ ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET) // )
        {
            if (s != 0)
            {
                printf("getnameinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("\tInterface : <%s>\n",ifa->ifa_name );
            printf("\t  Address : <%s>\n", host);
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
}


@end
```

I simply removed the test against wlan0 to see data.
ps You can remove "family"

Comment: Lovely. This is definitely pure C.

Comment: if `getnameinfo()` fails, then you don't call `freeifaddrs()` so your code may leak memory.

Answer (score 3):

I have been in the same issue recently, and this is the code I made up and it works. Make sure to use the name of the network interface, exactly as you have it (could be "eth0" or else).

gotta check if `ifconfig`command beforehand to get the interface name and use it in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
    

void extract_ipaddress()
    {
        //create an ifreq struct for passing data in and out of ioctl
        struct ifreq my_struct;
     
        //declare and define the variable containing the name of the interface
        char *interface_name="enp0s3";   //a very frequent interface name is "eth0";
     
        //the ifreq structure should initially contains the name of the interface to be queried. Which should be copied into the ifr_name field.
        //Since this is a fixed length buffer, one should ensure that the name does not cause an overrun
        size_t interface_name_len=strlen(interface_name);
     
        if(interface_name_len<sizeof(my_struct.ifr_name))
        {
            memcpy(my_struct.ifr_name,interface_name,interface_name_len);
            my_struct.ifr_name[interface_name_len]=0;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Copy name of interface to ifreq struct");
            printf("The name you provided for the interface is too long...\n");
        }
     
        //provide an open socket descriptor with the address family AF_INET
        /* ***************************************************************
         * All ioctl call needs a file descriptor to act on. In the case of SIOCGIFADDR this must refer to a socket file descriptor. This socket must be in the address family that you wish to obtain (AF_INET for IPv4)
         * ***************************************************************
         */
     
        int file_descriptor=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
     
        if(file_descriptor==-1)
        {
            perror("Socket file descriptor");
            printf("The construction of the socket file descriptor was unsuccessful.\n");
            return -1;
        }
     
        //invoke ioctl() because the socket file descriptor exists and also the struct 'ifreq' exists
        int myioctl_call=ioctl(file_descriptor,SIOCGIFADDR,&my_struct);
     
        if (myioctl_call==-1)
        {
            perror("ioctl");
            printf("Ooops, error when invoking ioctl() system call.\n");
            close(file_descriptor);
            return -1;
        }
     
        close(file_descriptor);
     
        /* **********************************************************************
         * If this completes without error , then the hardware address of the interface should have been returned in the  'my_struct.ifr_addr' which is types as struct sockaddr_in.
         * ***********************************************************************/
     
      //extract the IP Address (IPv4) from the my_struct.ifr_addr which has the type 'ifreq'
     
        /* *** Cast the returned address to a struct 'sockaddr_in' *** */
        struct sockaddr_in * ipaddress= (struct sockaddr_in *)&my_struct.ifr_addr;
       /* *** Extract the 'sin_addr' field from the data type (struct) to obtain a struct 'in_addr' *** */
      printf("IP Address is %s.\n", inet_ntoa(ipaddress->sin_addr));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the binary size, you can use iproute2 as library.

[iproute2-as-lib](https://github.com/eshenhu/iproute2_as_lib)

Pros:

- No need to write the socket layer code.
- More or even more information about network interfaces can be got. Same functionality with the iproute2 tools.
- Simple API interface.

Cons:

- iproute2-as-lib library size is big. ~500kb.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite easy way to get ip, by take advantage of using bash command:

```
hostname -I
```

but use "hostname -I" natively will print the result on screen, we need to use "popen()" to read result out and save it into a string, here is c code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // popen
#include "ip_common_def.h"

const char * get_ip()
{
    // Read out "hostname -I" command output
    FILE *fd = popen("hostname -I", "r");
    if(fd == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open pipe.\n");
    return NULL;
    }
    // Put output into a string (static memory)
    static char buffer[IP_BUFFER_LEN];
    fgets(buffer, IP_BUFFER_LEN, fd);

    // Only keep the first ip.
    for (int i = 0; i < IP_BUFFER_LEN; ++i)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == ' ')
        {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    char *ret = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    memcpy(ret, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    ret[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    return ret;
}
```