# Equivalent inet_addr for interface name (eth0, etc.) C/C++, Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get IP address of an interface on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283494/get-ip-address-of-an-interface-on-linux)

I have code such as the following:

```
const char* interface = "10.123.123.123";
struct ip_mreq mc_req;    
mc_req.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(interface);
```

where *interface* is the inet address of the interface I want to use.

How can I refer to the interface by *name* instead?

For example, I want to write something like:

```
const char* interface = "eth0";
struct ip_mreq mc_req;    
mc_req.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(interface);  // ???
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a function similar to inet_addr where I can lookup the inet address refering to "eth0"?

Comment: note: the search box on SO is your friend.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`getifaddrs()` will do the job.