# Detecting if a packet is from the local host via sockaddr_in*

Tags: networking, network-programming

I have a client which is subscribed to several multicast feeds via a third party library with a callback. The third party library does something like this:

```
sockaddr_in senderAddr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
for fd in allMulticastFeeds:
{
    recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&senderAddr, &len);    
    (*func)(buf, rc, &senderAddr, 0, stuff*);
}
```

Several listeners subscribe to me, and my job is to parse the messages contained in buf and callback on the appropiate clients subscribed to me. One of the options clients who subscribe to me give me is whether they want to receive messages outgoing from the local host or not. Because different subscribers to me might want different behavior I simply cannot translate this to a disabling of multicast and I must, for each client, check whether he or she requested local messages, and if not, then hand them over only if I can verify from the `sockaddr_in` that they are not local.

My approach to do this was to do the following in the constructor of my service:

```
sockaddr_in self;
hostent *he;
char local[HOST_NAME_MAX];
gethostname(local, sizeof(local));
he = gethostbyname(local);

if (he)
{
    memcpy(&self.sin_addr, he->h_addr_list[0], he->h_length);
    selfAddr_ = self.sin_addr.s_addr;
}
```

where `selfAddr_` is a member variable of type `long`. Then, when I get the callback described above from the network listener I do something like this:

```
//code to get the correct listener for this type of packet after parsing it
if (listener->AskedForLocal || selfAddr_ != s_addr)
    listener->onFoo(bla,bla);
```

where `s_addr` is the `sin_addr.s_addr` contained in the `sockaddr_in*` I get from the third party library calling `recvfrom`. This seemed to work when I tested it but I have a feeling it is failing sometimes and it might have to do with the adhoc using of the first element of `he->h_addr_list`. Is this method unreliable and if so, is the only reliable method to check every element of the `he->h_addr_list` against the incoming `s_addr`?

Comment: If "different subscribers to me might want different behavior" then you aren't engaged in multicasting at all, and you should review your technology choice.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the constructor for your service and trying it on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS running as a virtualbox image I get selfAddr_ = 0x10107f
This corresponds to the loopback address 127.0.0.1

This might not be what you're looking for - I suspect you're probably after a specific network interface's IP address, if so try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283494/get-ip-address-of-an-interface-on-linux).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but somehow I don't see 0x10107f corresponding to 127.0.0.1... Shouldn't that be 0x0100007F...