# How do I get my IP address in C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, networking

How could I get my IP address (preferably in `192.168.0.1` format)?

Comment: See previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/get-the-ip-address-of-the-machine)

Comment: I'd like it in c code

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283494/get-ip-address-of-an-interface-on-linux

Comment: `const char* my_address = "127.0.0.1";` works most of the time.

Comment: You may have several IP addresses....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This example code lists both the interface name (e.g. `lo` or `eth0`) together with the currently assigned IP address, for all the IPv4 network interfaces that exist on your computer:

```
getifaddrs(&addrs);
tmp = addrs;

while (tmp) 
{
    if (tmp->ifa_addr && tmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in *pAddr = (struct sockaddr_in *)tmp->ifa_addr;
        printf("%s: %s\n", tmp->ifa_name, inet_ntoa(pAddr->sin_addr));
    }

    tmp = tmp->ifa_next;
}

freeifaddrs(addrs);
```

Comment: uClibc does not contain getifaddrs until very crecently. Do you know any other method which could be used on embedded devices?

Answer (score 7):

For Linux:

To get all interfaces local to the machine use [`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

There is an example at the end of the page linked above.